# Python, Tkinter log in box, unable to make username and password global?

Tags: python, tkinter

My code looks like this, I thought global username and global password would work, instead of printing the username/password it prints something similar to ".41238472L". How do I fix this? Thanks

```
from Tkinter import *

global username
global password
root = Tk()

def getName():
    root.destroy()

userLabel = Label(root, text="Enter Username")
username = Entry(root, bd=5)
pwLabel = Label(root, text="Enter Password" )
password = Entry(root, bd=5, show ='*')
submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = getName)

userLabel.pack()
username.pack()
pwLabel.pack()
password.pack()
submit.pack(side = BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()

print username
print password
```

Comment: `global` doesn't create global variable - `username = some_value` does it. `global` is used in function to inform function to use external/global variable instead of creating ocal variable.

Comment: Is there are way that I can use the username and password values after the root.mainloop()? Thanks

Comment: as @Lafexlof said `username` is `Entry` instance and you have to use `username.get()`. If you need this value after `mainloop()` then you have to assign to normal variable `var_username = username.get()` - for example in `getName()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widgets need a parent to exist. Even if a variable holds a widget instance, if that parent of said widget destroyed, you can not use its methods. So you can not get contents entries after destroying `root`. **But** you *can* bind a `StringVar` to `Entry` and get contents of `StringVar`.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()    
nameVar = StringVar()
passVar = StringVar()

def getName():
    root.destroy()

userLabel = Label(root, text="Enter Username")
username = Entry(root, bd=5, textvariable=nameVar)
pwLabel = Label(root, text="Enter Password" )
password = Entry(root, bd=5, textvariable=passVar, show ='*')
submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = getName)

userLabel.pack()
username.pack()
pwLabel.pack()
password.pack()
submit.pack(side = BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()

print nameVar.get()
print passVar.get()
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the .get() seems to only work before the root.mainloop(). The error that appears is, TclError: invalid command name. ".41238472L"

Answer (score 1):

You have to change variable names because now you use the same name for two different things. And then you can copy text from entry to variable .

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def get_name():
    # inform function to use global variables instead of local one
    global username
    global password

    # copy values
    username = entry_username.get()
    password = entry_password.get()

    root.destroy()

# --- main ---

# global variable

username = None
password = None

# GUI

root = tk.Tk()

label_username = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Username")
entry_username = tk.Entry(root, bd=5)
label_password = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Password" )
entry_password = tk.Entry(root, bd=5, show='*')
submit = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=get_name)

label_username.pack()
entry_username.pack()
label_password.pack()
entry_password.pack()
submit.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()

# result

print username
print password
```